# Understanding the showModalDialog

Tags: showmodaldialog

I have a shopping cart page where my 'Pay By Credit Card' button fires a popup:

window.showModalDialog(ccPaymentURL, null, "dialogwidth: 450px; dialogheight: 370px; center: yes; resizable: yes");

The URL loaded into this popup (an SSL page that sits in a different domain) collects the CC info, processes the charges and (via a webservice running on the orginal site) marks the order as 'Paid'.

At this point, the popup is supposed to refresh the parent - letting the parent requery the db and find that the order's been paid and re-display the updated order status.

My integration tests show everything working correctly. But in reality...some users are breaking the chain somewhere and the parent page is failing to reload. I suspect it has to do with how different browsers (and/or browser settings) treat showModalDialog so i'm looking for an overview of known things that can go wrong when trying to implement this sort of use case.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could there be some sort of cross-domain security policy that's preventing the complete chain from happening?

Or how's the error handling from within your pop-up?  Does it handle every case for what happens if the verification occurred successfully or not?